# Create bootable Windows 8.1 iso using ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8, iso

I'm wondering if anyone can give me some guidance as to how to create a bootable Windows 8.1 installation iso using Ubuntu/Linux. The deal is that I had to extract the files from an existing iso so I could make some mods to the configuration. Now I need to wrap the iso up again and boot into it using virtualbox.

For reasons I'd rather not go into, I can't create a bootable USB or CD, and I can't do this using Windows. Is there a pure Linux solution to my problem?

Comment: Take a look at [_here_](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-to-create-a-windows-8-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

Use WINUSB.
http://www.geekthis.net/blog/91/create-bootable-windows-usb-in-linux
Or for the (.deb) download use this link:
http://en.congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html